# class declared like UIImage (FiltrrCompositions) iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios5

i am new to iPhone and objective c

i want to know the meaning of below declaration..can anyone please tell me the answer

```
UIImage (FiltrrCompositions) iOS
```

Comment: The word you are looking for to use on google is an Objective-C "category".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Objective-C [Category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html), in other words Extension of existing class.

Comment: @Oner Thanks for your reply...can you please let me know how can we declare an object for this Category classes...if i declared like "UIImage (FiltrrCompositions) *obj;" it is showing error in xcode 4.2